# How to make responsive button group with label in same row

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a form which includes list of elements.It should be responsive and should be fit for all those screens.When I run that project,everthing looks good on big screen but when I make it smaller,that language label and its buttons getting seperated in such a bad way as you can see on the picture.How can I make it always together and in the same row?I want it to be seem as in the first image for big screens.

**BIG SCREEN**
[image]
**MOBILE**

[image]

Besides if I make that language text `h4`(like the other titles),that language label and those buttons became as bad as small size.Also I want that language label as `h4`.Here what I tried below

```
 <div class=" container shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="margin-top:50px;">
      <form class="form1" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:10px;">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <div class="example-button-row">
                <strong style="font-size:22px;">Language</strong>
                <button style="margin-left:10px;" mat-stroked-button>English</button>
                <button mat-stroked-button>German</button>
                </div>
                <br>
          </li>
          <li>
            <strong>
              <h4 for="">Server Size</h4>
            </strong>
            <hr>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to experiment with the `x-overflow` css-attribute of your divs, but that would defeat the purpose of using bootstaps responsive grid.
The idea behind responsive design, is not to make it look exactly the same on all sreensizes but to see if you can come up with ways to make the best of every individual size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label sr-only" for="input_2">Input 2</label>
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="left">
        <label class="btn btn-default active">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked>Opt1</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2">Opt2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#right {
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can utilize `d-flex` on `li`
and add `margin-right` to your `strong` or `h4` tag. This works fine even if you are in 320px resolution. Hope it helps
[Responsive at 320px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPpC0.png)

Just added this minor change

```
<li class="d-flex">
        <div class="example-button-row">
            <strong style="font-size:22px; margin-right:20px">Language</strong>
            <button mat-stroked-button>English</button>
            <button mat-stroked-button>German</button>
            </div>
      </li>
```